# How can you determine the nature of an object from its flight path angle, velocity, and radius alone?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

Assuming that a defense system is capable of determining an object's flight path angle ($\gamma$), velocity (*v*), and radius (r), how could one differentiate between an ICBM, a satellite, or a solar probe?

One could begin with the energy equation:

$$\epsilon = \frac {v^2}{2} -\frac{\mu}{r}$$

where $\mu$ is the gravitational parameter $G(M+m)$, and the sign of $\epsilon$ would help to differentiate the objects, since if:

$$\epsilon<0 = closed$$
$$\epsilon \geq 0 = open$$

Thus a negative value would indicate a closed orbit, meaning that the object is either an ICBM or satellite, while a positive value would indicate an open orbit, meaning that the object is a solar probe.

However, in cases where $\epsilon$ is negative, how could one use the flight path angle to differentiate between the two options?

Comment: By solar probe, you mean something in heliocentric orbit, not something investigating the sun, right?

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I refer to an object on a parabolic or hyperbolic orbit relative to Earth

Comment: no, but you can determine the nature of it's current trajectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the radial distance $r$, velocity $v$, flight path angle $\gamma$ in radians, gravitational parameter $\mu$, and specific orbital energy $\epsilon$,

the [specific relative angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_relative_angular_momentum) is

$$h= \|{\overrightarrow{r}  \times \overrightarrow{v}}\| = rv\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+ \gamma\right) =rv\cos\left( \gamma\right)$$

Then the [orbital eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) is

$$e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2\epsilon h^2}{\mu^2}}$$

and the [semimajor axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes#Energy;_calculation_of_semi-major_axis_from_state_vectors) is

$$a = -\frac{\mu}{2\epsilon}$$

That yields the [periapsis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) $q = a(1-e)$.

If $q$ is less than the radius of the planet being orbited, the object is on a suborbital path, and given the constraints of objects in the original question, would be an ICBM.

Comment: And yet a satellite falling out of orbit might be indistinguishable from a high-altitude ballistic missile.  I agree with your math but think the question is a bit vague.

Comment: A ballistic missile will have been detected at launch.  The US, Russia, and I assume many other countries all have extensive launch detection systems.  The US systems are so good they detected the surface-to-air missile that shot down Malaysia Airlines Flight 17 in 2014.  If you backtrack the object's path, an ICBM will have a launch event at its beginning, a falling satellite will not.